# How to get a current active CallSID of a worker with Twilio SDK?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How to get a current active CallSID of a worker with Twilio SDK?
I have the Worker SID and I need to get the CallSID of the current active call that of the worker.

Comment: How are you assigning the call to the worker?

Comment: With a the taskqueue

Answer (score 0):

The CallSid data is available from the [Taskrouter Assignment Callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-linked-call-tracking) event:

> Upon issuing a Dequeue Instruction, TaskRouter will update the
> TaskAttributes of the Task with a **worker_call_sid** to denote the
> **CallSid** that is being created for the outgoing call to a given worker.
>
> The TaskAttributes of the Task will then contain both the call_sid and
> worker_call_sid.

Your app will need to setup a webhook to listen for the assignment callback.

You could also use the Twilio REST API to [Fetch the Task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task?code-sample=code-fetch-task&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) and check the attributes directly:

```
var task = TaskResource.Fetch(
            pathWorkspaceSid: "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            pathSid: "WTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );
```

The [best practice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/rest-api-best-practices#avoid-unnecessary-fetching) that is recommended by Twilio is to use Webhooks and store the relevant call and task data within your app:

> If you are performing a large amount of GET requests, consider
> implementing webhooks aka StatusCallBack requests for the resource
> endpoint(s) your account is utilizing. The information contained in
> the responses posted to your servers will often remove the need to
> perform any future polling GET requests.
>
> If you are frequently fetching the same data from Twilio, we recommend
> moving the data from Twilio to your own servers. Once data has been
> successfully moved, delete data stored on Twilio servers if you no
> longer need it. Not only will this will reduce costs, this is also a
> generally recommended business practice for privacy, security, and
> compliance.